# how to get only name value in laravel please suggestion

Tags: laravel

```
->addColumn('name', function($data) {  
               
    $unitsdata = DB::table("units")
        ->select("id","name")
        ->where('owner_id')
        ->get();
        return $unitsdata;
})
```

This is my laravel code and i want only name value but my output is show in foll..

[i want name value with proper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqkdb.png)

Comment: You need to provide quality code examples for the community to be able to help you.  From what I see, you are trying to add a column to an existing query (which is not shown in your example) ?   If this is the case, have a look at ->with() function and try to use Laravel models in your code.  If you provide the complete query, maybe we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not use where properly

I think the solution could be like that

```
$unitsdata = DB::table("units")
                        ->select("id","name")
                        ->where('owner_id',1)
                        ->get();
                        return $unitsdata;

            })
```

where 1 is your owner id

Comment: i am correction in my code but ans is same no any change..

Comment: owner id is all tables im my datdabase.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this.

```
 $unitsdata = DB::table("units")
    ->where('owner_id',1)
    ->first()->name;
```

Hope that it will help you.